# How to decode this JSON with ZIO JSON?

Tags: zio, zio-json

With the following JSON, how to decode with ZIO JSON?

```
{
"substitutions": {
    "BRANCH_NAME": "main",
    "COMMIT_SHA": "e40addb0c8d8180ae3a13a470b6f3c56f2e2f29f",
    "REF_NAME": "main",
    "REPO_NAME": "data-query-service"
  }
}
```

Comment: here you have nice doc about some custom configuration:
https://github.com/zio/zio-json